# twitter REST api with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter

I am new to the world of AJAX and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to authenticate my JSON request. The API documentation is speaking in riddles to me. This is what I have so far-

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url : "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json?",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
          oauth_token : "myTokenHere",

      },
      error: function(){
          alert('you loooose, sucka');
      },
      success: function(){
         alert('in like Flynn');
      }

  });
```

Can somebody please throw me a bone here? Much appreciated

Comment: What is the problem? Does it throw any kind of error? Dont you get any kind of response from the twitter server?

Comment: This is a horrible idea... you dont want to expose this in JS.

Comment: Completely right, Nix. I was just looking for an solution. RyanJP: You're doing it wrong. Please implement this kind of requests in your serverside logic and get your fresh baked response from your server. Dont expose your twitter auth's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nix mentioned in the comment. Your approach of doing this kind of stuff is completely wrong. Please implement those requests to twitter in your serverside logic. You can get your desired content via AJAX i.e. with an REST interface, like: www.yourdomain.com/getTwitterStuff

This is much cleaner and you also wont expose your twitter o_auth.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Would this apply to most site API's then?

Comment: It depends. If you want to retrieve data that is accessible to everyone, theres no problem in building that logic clientside. Just remember that your javascript is technically viewable by everyone. A common pitfall is the cross-domain policy. You cant just simply call foreign domains within your javascript. But thats another topic. Just keep that in mind ;)

Comment: Right. So basically anything that requires a password should be done on the server side to avoid people being able to see it?

Comment: Yep. If you want todo something like a fancy AJAX login, you can submit the user entered password, but you shoould use https for that so that nobody can sniff it. Otherwise it is always a good idea, todo such things on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [jsOAuth](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth) ?
maybe this way it's a bit easier.
Here an [example](https://gist.github.com/979955)